# jquery UI sortable li element not dragging to the last element

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using jquery UI sortable on a list inside a div.Issue im facing is when i drag the top element after the last element it does not go all the way to the bottom but jumps in the middle. Also when the container in which the ul resides is hiding at the bottom the li element does not drag to the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote (and at least what you've tried so far) for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Please help the community to help you. Post the code you have tried, without it all we have is speculation.